# Add Text Input on MassAction and Receive it in Controller - Magento2 Product Grid

Tags: magento2, massaction, product-grid

I am trying to create a MassAction which accepts the Text Input and not Drop Down like Update Status which brings DropDown of Enable and Disable. Can someone please provide me correct XML file and PHP to get the action data?

Technically, I am trying to update Price of Multiple Product via MassAction with Formula. Please find attached Image for desire result.

[image]

Comment: Any success with this one ?  I am also facing something similar :)

Comment: HI, @Mayur Patil, you got any success here? I need same kind of function with input box in sales order grid. can you please help!

Answer (score 0):

> create
>   `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`
>   in your module add below code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <action name="status">
                <settings>
                    <type>status</type>
                    <label translate="true">Change status</label>
                    <actions>
                        <action name="0">
                            <type>enable</type>
                            <label translate="true">Enable in All Store Views</label>
                            <url path="catalog/product/massStatus"> //add your controller Path
                                <param name="status">1</param>
                            </url>
                        </action>
                        <action name="1">
                            <type>disable</type>
                            <label translate="true">Disable in All Store Views</label>
                            <url path="catalog/product/massStatus">
                                <param name="status">2</param>
                            </url>
                        </action>
                    </actions>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

**You can add your action instead of `<action name="status">`.**

Comment: Hi Rathod,Thank you for reply but this offers DropDown and I want a TextField as Input. In other words, I need to access the Price by entering in TextField upon MassAction where as your solution will show Dropdown with predefined options i.e. Enabled and Disable.